# AS3 Swap depths in Flash IDE without destroying movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

I have two movieclips, one is on top, one is on bottom. The top one is set to the second frame. I move it to the z axis bottom on the next frame, and for the remaining frames it plays all frames like it has been reset without any code (like I didn't tell it gotoAndStop(2)).

Image example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhCU5.gif (hard to tell by the frame rate, but the dark green box starts playing as if I didn't set it's frame once I move it below)

I know it doesn't have that issue when I code the depth swapping with setChildIndex, but the animations are lost.

If you're wondering, it's a simplified issue of a larger moving character sprite animation that I would like to swap depths of movie clips in the animation without resetting the movie clips underneath the depth change. So I'm not really looking for a work around per se, unless there's a well design solution and not a band aid "hack."

Comment: "I move it to the z axis bottom" -- how do you move it?

Answer (score 1):

I think I didn't understand your question fully. A MovieClip will keep playing or keep being stopped no matter what you do with it, even if it was removed from the scene. I made a simple example which shows that MovieClip state is not affected by depth change.

The working SWF is here to test: http://zdg.ru/tmp/updown.swf

And the code is:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var is_playing:Boolean = true;
btn_toggle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doToggle);
btn_updown.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doUpdown);

function doToggle(evt:MouseEvent) {
    if (is_playing) mv_test.stop(); else mv_test.play();
    is_playing = !is_playing;
}

function doUpdown(evt:MouseEvent) {
    var tmp:int = getChildIndex(mv_block);
    setChildIndex(mv_block, getChildIndex(mv_test));
    setChildIndex(mv_test, tmp);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's fine but if you try to re-arrange the depths through the Flash IDE (without using code) the new bottom layer MC is reset.

Comment: I don't understand how do you change depth. You have a timeline with 2 movieclips and at some frame there is a keyframe where these two clips' depths are swapped?

Comment: Yes, sorry for being unclear. I swap depths in the IDE using ctrl+shift+up/down.

Comment: I will try to solve that but meanwhile you can try swapping them without IDE means, just use the `function doUpdown` code to swap them in the appropriate frames.

Comment: The only solution I see for now is keeping one (animated) movieclip in one layer and having 2 more layers, one higher and one lower, and moving the other movieclip (non-animated) to either higher or lower layer.